# Разрешить доступ к порту 3306 только с определённого IP

Tags: linux, iptables

Как разрешить доступ к базе данных с фиксированного IP с помощью программы *iptables*?

Текущее состояние таблицы *filter*:

```
$ sudo iptables-save -t filter
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Jul 28 20:40:23 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:80]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jul 28 20:40:23 2016
```

Comment: ответ зависит от текущего содержимого и политики таблицы *filter*. приложите к вопросу вывод `$ sudo iptables-save -t filter`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin прикрепил правила iptables

Answer (score 1):

если для таблицы *filter* установлена политика `ACCEPT` (строка `:INPUT ACCEPT` в выводе `iptables-save`) **и** в таблице отсутствуют другие правила, то примерно так:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp \! -s ip-адрес --dport порт -j REJECT
```

т.е., отклонить все пакеты, приходящие по протоколу *tcp* **не** с указанного `ip-адреса` на указанный `порт`.

но в вашем конкретном случае, учитывая, что цепочка `INPUT` заканчивается правилом с директивой `REJECT` (строка `-A INPUT -j REJECT ...` в выводе `iptables-save`), добавлять это правило *netfilter-а* (изменив его логику на противоположную) надо не в конец цепочки `INPUT` (что делает команда `-A`), а где-нибудь выше финального правила. например, в самое начало цепочки (с помощью команды `-I` без аргумента):

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s ip-адрес --dport порт -j ACCEPT
```

т.е., **разрешить** все пакеты, приходящие по протоколу *tcp* с указанного `ip-адреса` на указанный `порт`.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, речь идёт о MySQL. Может я не знаю особенностей данного случая, но почему нельзя воспользоваться тем средством, из состава MySQL, которое именно для этого и предназначено - командой GRANT ? Вот, что про неё написано:

> С тем, чтобы можно было определять права пользователям с конкретных
>   компьютеров, в MySQL обеспечивается возможность указывать имя
>   пользователя (user_name) в форме user@host.

Можете вместо user задать % и получите разрешение заходить с host любому пользователю.